# app on an unsupported version of angular ( version 8 ) what are the implications of staying on an unsupported version

Tags: angular

Our App is on angular Version 8 which is unsupported at this point. what would this mean for the app ? do we really need to get on a supported version ?

Comment: What you mean by unsupported?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/releases#lts-fixes , based on the documentation , Angular version 8 is no longer supported. we are on version 8.

Comment: We are on angular 7 version in our projects and its working fine. The support thing is that if there's some issue in future with the angular project they won't help you with the debug but in my opinion if its already working fine then I don't think there's anything to worry about. Meanwhile you can update your project to latest stable lts version and it won't take much.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to maintain the project it won't really matter

There are some downsides though:

- The longer it's left on Ang 7/8 the harder it will be to upgrade to the latest version (Angular 11 at present)
- You need to use older versions of libraries that are compatible with older Angular versions (takes time to figure out and manage the versions)
- `Snyk` (often used in CI/CD) reports `npm` vulnerabilities. These may require 3rd party package updates - some of which may only be available for latest Anglar versions

But, saying all that, it's still JavaScript at the end of the day, and if it works well now it will most probably continue to do so